# Листинг вируса на с++, поражающего exe файлы, есть?

Tags: c++, вирусы

Листинг вируса на с++, поражающего exe файлы, есть?

Comment: А вот мне бы тоже было интересно, в учебных целях!

Comment: Может парень сис. админ и ему по работе нужно, вполне интересный вопрос для учебных целей, сори, @metazet, что повторяю  )

Comment: А их кто-то на нем пишет  ???

Answer (score 1):

Вот книга, может что интересное подчерпнёшь. Компьютерные вирусы изнутри и снаружи. Крис Касперски.

Comment: пасибо, щас скачаю)